# node.js readline (or similar) tool to manage a better prompt interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline, read-eval-print-loop

I am using `readline` to manage a program that will have events emitted to it from a websocket connection. The problem I have is that when messages are emitted to stdout, the formatting of the tty is broken in that the input line doesn't stay at the bottom of the screen.  Here's example code:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

function getInput() {
  rl.question("SEND> ", function (answer) {
    if (answer.trim() === "quit") {
      rl.close();
      ws.close();
      process.exit();
    } else {
      ws.send(answer);
    }
  });
}

const ws = new WebSocket("wss://websocket-echo.com/");

ws.on("open", function open() {
  console.log("connected -- begin sending nonsense to console");
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(` SPAM: ${(Math.random() + 1).toString()}`);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
  }, 5000);
  getInput();
});

ws.on("close", function close() {
  console.log("disconnected");
});

ws.on("message", function message(data) {
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
  console.log(`RECV> ${data}`);
  getInput();
});
```

The output overwrites the input line. I was hoping there is a library that helps manage this so that output stays above the input line. Are there any tools that can facilitate this behavior? Ultimately I am looking for a better prompt interface when a new line is added to stdout.

Comment: npm package `inquirer` also offers layout options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer#user-content-user-interfaces-and-layouts

Comment: hmm... doesn't this meet the "looking for tools recommendations" qualification of [things that aren't on topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: This question was mentioned on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421820/yet-another-flag-declined-what-should-i-have-done-differently).

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem and I solved it with a library called [blessed.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed)
With this library you can create different elements (Textboxes,Prompts,..) similar to a HTML DOM.

To achieve your goal I modified your code like this:

First we require `blessed` instead of `readline`:

```
const blessed = require('blessed')
```

Then we are creating a screen (You can imagine this as a container where all elements of our application get added):

```
//Creating Screen
let screen = blessed.screen()
```

After that we create three elements and add them to our screen:

```
//Box that will contain all Messages
let messages = blessed.box({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: '100%-1',
  width: '100%',
  alwaysScroll: true,
  scrollable: true,
})

//SEND> Prefix for Textbox
var messageInputPrefix = blessed.text({
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: 1,
  width: 6,
  content: 'SEND> ',
})

//Message Input
var messageInput = blessed.textbox({
  bottom: 0,
  left: 6,
  height: 1,
  width: '100%-6',
  keys: true,
  mouse: true,
  inputOnFocus: true,
})

screen.append(messages)
screen.append(messageInputPrefix)
screen.append(messageInput)
```

The elements are positioned (With the `top`,`left`,`bottom`,`height`,`width` properties) like this:

[image: Console Interface explanation]

I then added a key press listener to the `screen` and `messageInput` element that closes the application when the user presses `Escape` or `Ctrl+C`. If you do not want this behavior you can remove those two lines:

```
screen.key(['escape', 'C-c'], (ch, key) => process.exit(0))
messageInput.key(['escape', 'C-c'], (ch, key) => process.exit(0))
```

We also need a `submit` event (When the user presses `Enter`) for the `messageInput` that adds the user input to the `messages` element:

```
//Append Message to the messages box
//Always scroll to bottom after appending
const addMessage = (text) => {
  messages.pushLine(text)
  //Scroll to bottom of the element
  messages.setScrollPerc(100)

  //Updates the screen
  screen.render()
}

//Textbox Submit Event
messageInput.on('submit', (text) => {
  if (text.trim() === 'quit') {
    ws.close()
    process.exit()
  } else {
    ws.send(text)
  }
  messageInput.clearValue()
  addMessage(text)
  messageInput.focus()
})
```

Finally we create the Websocket connection and all of its event listeners:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://websocket-echo.com/')

ws.on('open', function open() {
  addMessage('connected -- begin sending nonsense to console')
  setInterval(() => {
    addMessage(`SPAM: ${(Math.random() + 1).toString()}`)
  }, 5000)
})

ws.on('close', function close() {
  addMessage('disconnected')
})

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  addMessage(`RECV> ${data}`)
})

// Focus messageInput on application start
messageInput.focus()
```

Complete code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const blessed = require('blessed')

//Creating Screen
let screen = blessed.screen()

//Box that will contain all Messages
let messages = blessed.box({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: '100%-1',
  width: '100%',
  alwaysScroll: true,
  scrollable: true,
})

//SEND> Prefix for Textbox
var messageInputPrefix = blessed.text({
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  height: 1,
  width: 6,
  content: 'SEND> ',
})

//Message Input
var messageInput = blessed.textbox({
  bottom: 0,
  left: 6,
  height: 1,
  width: '100%-6',
  keys: true,
  mouse: true,
  inputOnFocus: true,
})

screen.append(messages)
screen.append(messageInputPrefix)
screen.append(messageInput)

//Escape or Ctrl+C Ends Application
screen.key(['escape', 'C-c'], (ch, key) => process.exit(0))
messageInput.key(['escape', 'C-c'], (ch, key) => process.exit(0))

//Append Message to the messages box
//Always scroll to bottom after appending
const addMessage = (text) => {
  messages.pushLine(text)
  //Scroll to bottom of the element
  messages.setScrollPerc(100)

  //Updates the screen
  screen.render()
}

//Textbox Submit Event
messageInput.on('submit', (text) => {
  if (text.trim() === 'quit') {
    ws.close()
    process.exit()
  } else {
    ws.send(text)
  }
  messageInput.clearValue()
  addMessage(text)
  messageInput.focus()
})



const ws = new WebSocket('wss://websocket-echo.com/')

ws.on('open', function open() {
  addMessage('connected -- begin sending nonsense to console')
  setInterval(() => {
    addMessage(`SPAM: ${(Math.random() + 1).toString()}`)
  }, 5000)
})

ws.on('close', function close() {
  addMessage('disconnected')
})

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  addMessage(`RECV> ${data}`)
})

// Focus messageInput on application start
messageInput.focus()
```

If you have any questions regarding this code I recommend you the `blessed` documentation that you can find here:

https://github.com/chjj/blessed

Of course you can also comment your question down here and I will try help you!